# How to perform backup with Azure App Service

Tags: azure

I tried backing up Azure App Service according to the following URL.

However, if you press the backup button on the App Service menu, the next screen will be displayed and you will not be able to proceed.

> Backup Not Configured, Configure you backup by setting up a storage account, schedule and select databases to be backed up for safe keeping and disaster recovery.

[image]

I tried the App Service Plan with Standard and Premium.
I also created Azure Storage Account.
I have created a new App Service in several regions.

However, both of them got the same result.
Does anyone know the procedure?

Best regards.

Comment: I'm currently running into the same issue. I have some App Services I need to configure for backup and am seeing the same thing you are in your screenshot. I have other App Services that I've already configured for backup and there is a big "Configure" button below that message that I believe should be showing up. When I attempt to configure an existing backup, I'm presented with a blade that just waits (the sliding dots). I'm going to file a ticket with Azure support at this point as I believe it's an issue on their end. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Backup and Restore feature in Azure App Service lets you easily create app backups manually or on a schedule. Also, remember, the Backup and Restore feature requires the App Service plan to be in the Standard tier or higher. However, before backup any Azure App Service you need to configure it properly. As your error message said you should configure,

Storage Account,
Schedule and
Select the Databases to backups

To configure your backups please follows below steps.

***Configure Manual Backup***

1. In the Azure portal, navigate to your app's blade, select Settings, then Backups. The Backups blade is displayed.

[image: Azure App Service Backup Settings]

2. In the Backups blade, click Configure.
3. In the Backups Configuration blade, click Storage Settings: Storage not configured to configure a storage account.

[image: Azure-App-Service-Bkp-Configuration]

4. Choose storage account Choose your backup destination by selecting a Storage Account and Container. The storage account must belong to the same subscription as the app you want to backup. If you wish, you can create a storage account or a new container in the respective blades. When you're done, click Select.

[image: Azure-App-Service-Backup-Settings-Storage-Account-Select]

5. In the Backups Configuration blade that is still left open, click Database Settings, then select the databases you want to include in the backups. (SQL database, MySQL, or PostgreSQL) (In my case I don’t have any database to select)
6. In the Backups Configuration blade, click Save. At this point you can click Backup button in the command bar of the Backups blade, this will create a Manual Backup of your app.

***Configure Schedule Backup***

7. On the Backups Configuration blade, set Schedule backup to On. Then configure the backup schedule as desired.

[image: Azure-App-Service-Bakup-Settings-Schedule]

8. In the Backups Configuration blade, click Save. That’s it your backups should works now as you scheduled.

Comment: I read some article that Azure will backup the database automatically when you create one in Azure. Or I have been mis-informed?

Answer (score 1):

The "Configure" option appeared for me after I tried logging into the Azure portal in private/incognito mode. I'd also recommend clearing out your cache for good measure. Hope that helps.

Comment: The reason is not clear, but I logged in again after a while (about half a day) passed and the Configure button was displayed.